# Problem retrieving data from Interactive Brokers using R IBrokers package

Tags: r, ibrokers

I have trouble retrieving EURUSD and GBPUSD currency pairs historical data from IB. The code I use works fine with CHFUSD and USDJPY but with EURUSD and GBPUSD I get a pending execution "waiting for TWS reply on EUR ...." which never ends.

I have tried this code for getting EURUSD and GBPUSD currency pairs historical data from IB.

```
require(IBrokers)
require(data.table)

tws <- twsConnect(port=7497)

contract <- twsCurrency(symbol="EUR",currency='USD',exch='IDEALPRO',primary='',strike='0.0',right='',local='',multiplier='',include_expired='0',conId=0)

xx <- IBrokers::reqHistoricalData(tws, Contract=contract, barSize="5 min",  endDateTime="20220426 13:00:00", duration="1 D", whatToShow="BID")
```

I expect it to retrieve an xts object for EURUSD and GBPUSD just as it does with CHFUSD and USDJPY, but the result is a pending execution "waiting for TWS reply on EUR ...." which never ends. It would be much appreciated if anyone could help me figure this out and get EURUSD, GBPUSD data.